# Модули для OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Привет, ребята. Ищу модуль для интеграции для 1c:предприятие? Кто-нибудь знает, хороший бесплатный модуль, который стабильно работает? Так же нужен модуль "Недавно просмотренные товары. Я сам обыскался, но найти не могу. Желательно бесплатные, но если нет бесплатных, но есть платные, то какие вы знаете?

Comment: 1.5 или 2.х? ибо важно

Comment: 2.x я уже просто найти никак не могу

Comment: https://www.opencart.ru/1c